# Как заставить анимацию повторяться после окончания последнего keyframes?

Tags: css3, css-animation

Подскажите, как заставить анимацию повторяться после окончания последнего keyframes?

```css
.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 800px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
img{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
.carousel-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-300px) rotateY(0);
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 352px;
  height: 222px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(1) {
  left: -100%;
  transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(180px);
  animation: carouselTwo 4s linear, carouselThree 4s 4s linear, carouselOne 4s 8s linear, infinite;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(180px);
  animation: carouselOne 4s linear, carouselTwo 4s 4s linear, carouselThree 4s 8s linear, infinite;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(180px);
  animation: carouselThree 4s linear, carouselOne 4s 4s linear, carouselTwo 4s 8s linear, infinite;
}

 @keyframes 
carouselOne {
   0% {
     transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: 0%;
   }
   25% {
     transform: rotateY(6deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -20%;
   }
   50% {
     transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -50%;
   }
   75% {
     transform: rotateY(21deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -70%;
   }
   100% {
     transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -100%;
   }
 }
@keyframes
carouselTwo {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: -100%;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(18deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: -60%;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 0%;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(-12deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 40%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes
carouselThree {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 100%;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(-24deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 80%;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(-9deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 0%;
  }

}
body { background: #202126; }
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-content">
    <img class="carousel-item" src="https://dvynr1wh82531.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/default_images/noImg_2.jpg"></img>
    <img class="carousel-item" src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png"></img>
    <img class="carousel-item" src="http://www.vbcdevelopers.com/images/no-image.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: укажите явное значение `animation-iteration-count`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 800px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
img{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
.carousel-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-300px) rotateY(0);
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 352px;
  height: 222px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(1) {
  left: -100%;
  transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(180px);
  animation: carouselTwo 4s linear 0s infinite;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(180px);
  animation: carouselOne 4s linear 0s infinite;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(180px);
  animation: carouselThree 4s linear 0s infinite;
}

 @keyframes 
carouselOne {
   0% {
     transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: 0%;
   }
   25% {
     transform: rotateY(6deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -20%;
   }
   50% {
     transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -50%;
   }
   75% {
     transform: rotateY(21deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -70%;
   }
   100% {
     transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(180px);
     left: -100%;
   }
 }
@keyframes
carouselTwo {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: -100%;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(18deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: -60%;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 0%;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(-12deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 40%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes
carouselThree {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 100%;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(-24deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 80%;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(-9deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(180px);
    left: 0%;
  }

}
body { background: #202126; }
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-content">
    <img class="carousel-item" src="https://dvynr1wh82531.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/default_images/noImg_2.jpg"></img>
    <img class="carousel-item" src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png"></img>
    <img class="carousel-item" src="http://www.vbcdevelopers.com/images/no-image.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нет, вы просто удалили кейфреймы кроме одного, и анимация выполняется вообще не так, на каждом элементе должно быть в анимации по 3 сценария, которые выполняются в разной очередности, в зависимости от начальной позиции элемента